# PuTTY maximize on full-screen exit

Tags: putty, fullscreen

When you exit full-screen in PuTTY, it goes back into a non-maximized state, regardless of whether it was maximized or not before going full-screen.

Is there a way to make it return to maximized mode, or even just return to the state it was in? Shrinking has the unpleasant side-effect of truncating long lines that had been displayed when maximized/full-screen.

Comment: if you can't find a workaround (or even if you can), consider checking the known-bugs list and file a bug with the PuTTY team if the behavior you describe isn't listed: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/feedback.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to always use PuTTY in the same 2 modes (maximized and full screen), you can set a constant size in the Window Preferences and then select **Forbid Resizing Completely**:

[image]

I'm not sure on your screen resolution, but you can play around with the columns and rows until it is the same size as a maximized window. Then ensure you check off **forbid resizing completely** and this window size will be restored when coming out of full screen mode.

Another solution is to use [Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com):

```
#ifwinactive ahk_class PuTTY
!Enter::
Send {Alt down}{Enter down}{Alt up}{Enter up}
Winmaximize
return
#ifwinactive
```

This will toggle between fullscreen mode and maximized mode. Script tested and working on Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7.

Comment: If I use the **forbid resizing completely** option, it seems I can no longer go into full-screen mode. The Autohotkey solution almost works, but goes through the "non-maximized" state before maximizing, which keeps the undesired side-effect of truncating long lines in the terminal.

Comment: How about using the option **When window is resized: change the number of rows and columns** but also set your rows and columns very high so it appears maximized already? That way when you transfer out of full-screen it will still be large and not truncate the text.

Comment: You're very welcome :)